# iOs - Using container, table view and detailed view - How do I keep detailed view inside container

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, storyboard, containers

I'm trying to create a pretty simple app, although I'm stuck on the same issue for days...
I'm using storyboard and my current set up is this:
[storyboard](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-uICDMZ0KWfo/UqWco6AVW3I/AAAAAAAAGq4/dPFq4VT6ucE/w667-h378-no/Screen+Shot+2013-12-09+at+12.30.45+PM.png)

My goal is to keep everything in the "Project View Controller" the same except for what happens inside the container.
The "Comments Table View" shows ok inside my container but when tapping a cell in the tableview, the "Comment Show View" covers the whole screen (note that in storyboard, it inherits the size correctly).
This is how my "prepareForSegue" looks like (I tried fixing the size of the instance to the tableview size):

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showComment"] ){
    CommentShowViewController *csvc = [segue destinationViewController];

    [[csvc view] setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    NSIndexPath *path = [commentsTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Comment *c = [aCommentsList objectAtIndex:[path row]];
    [csvc setCurrent:c];

}
}
```

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the push segue. Push segues needs a `UINavigationController` to be performed. I guess you have a `UINavigationController` to the left in the picture that's not shown. When the segue is performed this is the `UINavigationController` that is used for the segue.

One fix for this issue would be to have another `UINavigationController` between the `ProjectViewController` and the `CommentsTableView`.

Container -> UINavigationController ->CommentsTableView -> CommentShowViewController.

Uncheck "Shows Navigation Bar" in IB if you don't want it to show.

Comment: One question on this solution. I've had a similar issue and when I stick the additional uinavigationcontroller between the container and the initial tableviewcontroller it complains of missing properties that I'm passing in the prepareForSegue method. This is because it's trying to pass the data to the navigationcontroller not the target uitableviewController. Is there a step missing here?

Comment: Probably,`segue.destinationViewController` will return the `UINavigationController`. You need to use `segue.destinationViewController.topViewController` instead.